# Display return value of method of class on a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code for class in App code folder is as

```
public class Circle
{
    public int _Radius;
    public float _PI = 3.14F;
    public Circle(int Radius)
    {
        this._Radius = Radius;
    }
    public string Area()
    {
        return _PI * _Radius * _Radius;
    }

}
```

and in code behind file i created object of this class as

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Circle C1 = new Circle(10);
    string text = C1.Area;

}
```

I wanna to display value `C1.Area` on label how i do this

Answer (score 0):

Simply assign the output to text property of your ASP Label control like this:-

```
lblMyLabel.Text = C1.Area();
```

Here I have considered you Label Control looks like this:-

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMyLabel" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'Area' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? E:\MZDotNet\WebSite4\Default.aspx.cs 13 24 WebSite4

Comment: @user3789138 - You forgot the parenthesis and I blindly copy pasted the same :P. Please try now.

Answer (score 0):

define a label like this in your .aspx page

```
<asp:Label ID="lblArea" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

And in code behind assign the value like this

```
lblArea.Text=C1.Area() ;
```

Comment: Error 1 Cannot convert method group 'Area' to non-delegate type 'string'. Did you intend to invoke the method? E:\MZDotNet\WebSite4\Default.aspx.cs 13 24 WebSite4

Comment: Your Area is a method.I missed the Bracket.An Edit has been made check.